# Как правильно экспортировать воксельную модель в юнити?

Tags: unity3d, графика

**Я понимаю из за чего не совпадают цвета, но как сделать чтобы импортировались все материалы? В данном случае стекло.**

[image: MagicaVoxel]
[image: Unity]

Comment: Материалы из других программ не импортируются. Для видеоигр материалы из 3д редакторов тупо не годятся, прожёрливые, другая система освещения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Материалы из MagicaVoxel не импортируются. То есть проводишь импорт в юнити, а потом уже создаешь и настраиваешь материалы в юнити.

Здесь пример настройки весьма простенького материала стекла:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfMZfZeeNGA

Т.к. стоковых шейдеров практически наверняка тебе не хватит, стит обратить внимание на изучение ShaderGraph.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того в какой **программе** ты делал эту модель.

Если в **MagicaVoxel** то, насколько я знаю импортировать материалы в другую программу является **не возможным**.

Comment: Да, делал в MagicaVoxel. Прикольно, я не представляю тогда что делать... Ну то что у меня получается и то что в юнити - совершенно разные модели. Странно почему тогда хвалят воксельную графику и Magica? Есть ли альтернативы лучше?

Comment: Ну насчет других вариантов не знаю, так что сорян.